# How to use WWW class with wcf ib Unity3D

Tags: wcf, unity-game-engine, video-streaming

In my app I'm connecting to WFC service.
I'm trying to get video file from this service. 
I'm using this code to connect to service:

```
TransferServiceClient client = new TransferServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost:4100/Service1.svc?singleWsdl"));
```

WWW class can get video stream and play it from url string.
Is it possible to use my WCF service with WWW. In other case, are there any suggessions how can I get video from wcf in my unity project?